# organize chinese character in text one word per line

Tags: shell, command-line

I was trying to organize a text file of chinese characters like this:

```
跌价

跌倒

跌停板

跌價

跌宕

跌幅

跌盪

跌眼鏡
```

I need to arrange them to one word per line. But I have no idea about how to get the word boundary. I mean for operating english, we can find it by space so the regex is something like \s[A-za-z], for chinese characters I don't know how to do it. Can someone tell me how to organize them to the format of one word per line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use `.`

```
awk '$0{gsub(/./,"&\n");printf $0}' input
```

test

```
kent$  echo "跌价

跌倒

跌停板

跌價

跌宕

跌幅

跌盪

跌眼鏡"|awk '$0{gsub(/./,"&\n");printf $0}'             
跌
价
跌
倒
跌
停
板
跌
價
跌
宕
跌
幅
跌
盪
跌
眼
鏡
```

Comment: I see, thank you. I was trying to use something like awk '{print $1}' file but didn't work.. now I see. XieXie!